# Encode $stateParams on angular ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular ui-router. I would like to encode the `$stateParams` with base64 encoding. For example:

`http://example.com/profile/6013/details`

to

`http://example.com/profile/kfnvjodu==/details`

Answer (score 1):

To encode a string in base64 format we use `btoa()` function and to decode the same encoded string we use `atob()` function.

**Example:**

```
var x="angular js";
var encodedString = btoa(x); // result: YW5ndWxhciBqcw==
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);// result: angular js
```

So if you encode like this `"http://example.com/profile/"+btoa(6013)+"/detials"` will result you this  url `http://example.com/profile/NjAxMw==/detials`

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.go = function (params) {
    $location.path(decodeURIComponent(params));
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to encode a URI.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
    var res = encodeURI(uri);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```